# How to pass location on parent relativelayout

Tags: android, listener, adapter, android-relativelayout

I have a imageview and need to know the size and position on screen of the relativelayout, so the dialog pops right over the relativelayout.

imageview is inside the relativelayout and the listener is inside a adapter, and need to pass the information correctly

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
ViewHolder vHolder;
if (convertView != null)
    vHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
else {
    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.car_list, null);
    vHolder = new ViewHolder();
    vHolder.textView = ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvCarListText));
    vHolder.textView2 = ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvCarDescriptionListText));
    vHolder.imageView = ((ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivCarListMenuIcon));
    vHolder.relativeLayout = ((RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout));
    convertView.setTag(vHolder);


    vHolder.imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final Rect rect = new Rect();
            v.getGlobalVisibleRect(rect);
            showCarEditDialog(rect); //THIS NEED TO PASS RELATIVELAYOUT POSITION ON SCREEN<-------------                            
        }
    });
}
return convertView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i manage to find the answer but still is not like i imagine it does not fit perfectly over the relativelayout

```
        vHolder.imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final View parent = (View)v.getParent();
                final int[] screenLocation = new int[2];
                parent.getLocationOnScreen(screenLocation);
                final int width = parent.getWidth();
                final int height = parent.getHeight();
                showCarEditDialog(Integer.parseInt(v.getTag().toString()), screenLocation[0], screenLocation[1], width, height);
            }
        });
```

[image: does not fit ok]

and the dialog code

```
private void showCarEditDialog(int position, int x,int y,int width,int height) {
    final Dialog mDialog = new Dialog(this.context);
    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    final LinearLayout mDialogView = (LinearLayout) mInflater.inflate(R.layout.car_edit, null);
    mDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    mDialog.setContentView(mDialogView);
    WindowManager.LayoutParams lp=mDialog.getWindow().getAttributes();
    lp.x=x;lp.y=y;lp.width=width;lp.height=height;lp.gravity= Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
    lp.dimAmount=0;
    mDialog.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
    mDialog.show();
}
```

Comment: still need some help on this, how i make it fit over the relativelayout

Comment: there is another way to get the location besides view.getLocationOnScreen(screenLocation) ??????